# How to alias an impl trait?

Tags: rust, traits

I have many functions of the following type signature:

```rust
fn f() -> impl Fn(u32) -> u32 { 
    |x: u32| x 
}
```

How can I give a name to `Fn(u32) -> u32` so that I don't have to repeat it? Although I can do `type X = Fn(u32) -> u32;`, Rust will not let me use this because it is a type and not a trait. Must I wait for [`trait_alias`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/unstable-book/language-features/trait-alias.html) or can I do something else?

Comment: It's not clear -- do you have many functions that all return *the same* type implementing `Fn(u32) -> u32`, or many functions that all return *different* types (different closures) which all implement `Fn(u32) -> u32`? I'm guessing the second one?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're exactly right. `impl X` requires `X` to be a trait, and it's impossible to have proper trait aliases until [trait aliases](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/41517) land. When that happens you'll be able to do this:

```
#![feature(trait_alias)]

trait X = Fn(u32) -> u32;

fn f() -> impl X {
    |x: u32| x
}
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c205d52442f27d01e8613fdc0eb33cee)

---

Alternatively, when [Permit impl Trait in type aliases](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/63063) lands, you'll be able to make `impl trait` a *type* alias. This is slightly different though. When we alias with `type X = impl Trait`, the compiler will ensure that every usage of `X` is actually the same concrete type. That would mean that, in your case, you wouldn't be able to use this with multiple different closures, since every closure has its own unique type.

```
#![feature(type_alias_impl_trait)]

type X = impl Fn(u32) -> u32;

fn f() -> X {
    |x: u32| x
}
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f5f06b2e828dd3f596d9317df69795fc)

However, this *won't compile*.

```
#![feature(type_alias_impl_trait)]

type X = impl Fn(u32) -> u32;

fn f() -> X {
    |x: u32| x
}

// Even a closure with exactly the same form has a different type.
fn g() -> X {
    |x: u32| x
}
```

The error is

```
error: concrete type differs from previous defining opaque type use
  --> src/lib.rs:10:1
   |
10 | / fn g() -> X {
11 | |     |x: u32| x
12 | | }
   | |_^ expected `[closure@src/lib.rs:7:5: 7:15]`, got `[closure@src/lib.rs:11:5: 11:15]`
   |
note: previous use here
  --> src/lib.rs:6:1
   |
6  | / fn f() -> X {
7  | |     |x: u32| x
8  | | }
   | |_^
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6e7cfb3e65efe635682fae1451671a3d)

This is in contrast to trait aliases, which would allow a different concrete type to be used with every function returning `impl TraitAlias`. See the RFCs that introduced [this syntax](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2515-type_alias_impl_trait.md) and [existential types in general](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2071-impl-trait-existential-types.md) for more.

---

Until one of those two features lands, you can get similar behavior to the trait alias with what is essentially a hack. The idea is to make a new trait which is essentially equivalent to the original trait, but has a shorter name.

```
// This trait is local to this crate,
// so we can implement it on any type we want.
trait ShortName: Fn(u32) -> u32 {}

// So let's go ahead and implement `ShortName`
// on any type that implements `Fn(u32) -> u32`.
impl<T: Fn(u32) -> u32> ShortName for T {}

// We can use `ShortName` to alias `Fn(u32) -> u32`.
fn f() -> impl ShortName {
    |x: u32| x
}

// Moreover, the result of that can be used in places
// that expect `Fn(u32) -> u32`.
fn g<T: Fn(u32) -> u32>(x: &T) -> u32 {
    x(6_u32)
}

fn main() {
    // We only know that `x` implements `ShortName`,
    let x = f();
    // But we can still use `x` in `g`,
    // which expects an `Fn(u32) -> u32` argument
    let _ = g(&x);
}
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a77bb7beed4911bceb0cc60638121a9c)

Comment: Aliasing an existential type is *quite* different from aliasing a trait, which is why I asked the OP for clarification in the question comments. Neither is necessarily incorrect, but your answer should at least mention that they do different things.

Comment: @trentcl I've clarified the difference. Thanks for letting me know. I'd assumed that they were the same, but I guess not.

Comment: I like the hack. Thanks!