# How to use a function as a generics argument in rust?

Tags: function, generics, rust

I want to write a small neural network in rust from scratch. For best performance, I want to give the rust compiler full knowledge of all vector and matrix sizes and functions used, so it can do as many optimizations as possible. I'm trying to add an activation function as a generic argument to the neural network layer, but it generates a compilation error. Here is what I tried:

```
type VectorFn<const vector_size: usize> = fn(&[f32; vector_size], &mut [f32; vector_size]);

struct Layer<
const input_size: usize,
const output_size: usize,
const activation_fn: VectorFn<output_size>  // error about output_size: the type of const parameters must not depend on other generic parameters
> {
    /// weights
    w: [[f32; input_size]; output_size],

    /// biases
    b: [f32; output_size],
}

// ...
```

I later want to use the `Layer` like so:

```
fn VectorizedFn<ScalarFunction>: VectorFn {  # this is pseudo code
    // ...
}
type VectorizedRelu = VectorizedFn<|x| max(x, 0)>  # this is pseudo code

let layer = Layer<32, 64, VectorizedRelu>::new();
```

I think I have two problems:
1.) There are two cases where I want to hand over a function as a generics argument. The first one is the line where the compiler complains about `output_size`. The second one is the `VectorizedFn<ScalarFunction>`. I don't know how to write them.
2.) How to write the functions and "subtypes" of those functions. Do they all have the same type, e.g. something like `fn(&[f32; vector_size], &mut [f32; vector_size])` ?

Comment: [This answers the title](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36390665/6274355), but I think most of your question is problems with const.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll split this into two parts: taking a function as a generic, and making an alias for a function trait.

## Taking a function as a generic

First, you want a regular generic, not a const generic. I've made your struct simpler so there's less extra info. There are three function traits in Rust: [`FnOnce`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnOnce.html), [`FnMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnMut.html), and [`Fn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Fn.html). This uses `FnMut`.

```rs
pub struct Layer<const INPUT_SIZE: usize, F> {
    w: [f32; INPUT_SIZE],
    b: [f32; INPUT_SIZE],
    activation: F,
}

impl<const INPUT_SIZE: usize, F> Layer<INPUT_SIZE, F>
where
    F: FnMut(&[f32; INPUT_SIZE], &mut [f32; INPUT_SIZE]),
{
    pub fn activate(&mut self) {
        (self.activation)(&self.b, &mut self.w);
    }
}
```

Functions (not function pointers) and closures with no captured state have a zero-sized type, so you don't need to worry about `activation` taking up extra space in your struct unless it needs to, and when you call this, the function will be able to be optimized just like a regular function call.

## Trait aliases

In order to avoid writing the function trait signature every time, you can create a "trait alias". This is an informal name for a trait that has no function besides hiding another trait.

```rs
pub trait VectorFn<const VECTOR_SIZE: usize>:
    FnMut(&[f32; VECTOR_SIZE], &mut [f32; VECTOR_SIZE])
{
}

impl<const VECTOR_SIZE: usize, F> VectorFn<VECTOR_SIZE> for F where
    F: FnMut(&[f32; VECTOR_SIZE], &mut [f32; VECTOR_SIZE])
{
}
```

This consists of two parts. The trait declaration of `VectorFn` has a const generic, which is then used in its supertrait `FnMut`. This ensures you can use any `VectorFn` just like a `FnMut`. Then, there is a blanket implementation for every `F` that implements the supertrait. This ensures you can use any `FnMut` whenever a `VectorFn` is required.

Note that when making aliases of the function traits, the function arguments must be generics, while the return type should be one or more associated types, in order to match the [`FnOnce` declaration](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnOnce.html).

Now you can use `VectorFn` in your type's implementation.

```rs
impl<const INPUT_SIZE: usize, F> Layer<INPUT_SIZE, F>
where
    // F: FnMut(&[f32; INPUT_SIZE], &mut [f32; INPUT_SIZE]),
    F: VectorFn<INPUT_SIZE>,
{
    pub fn activate(&mut self) {
        (self.activation)(&self.b, &mut self.w);
    }
}
```

Related:

- [How do you pass a Rust function as a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36390665/6274355)
- [How to alias an impl trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57937436/6274355)

Comment: It feels odd to have to use the field `activation: F` while I just want a static function call. Are you sure that there is no way to do `F(&self.b, &mut self.w);` instead of `(self.activation)(&self.b, &mut self.w);`?

Comment: @DanielS. The function traits require an existing (possibly zero-sized) value to call them on, so if you don't want that, you should make your own trait with an associated function. However, there should be very little difference when using a zero-sized type for `F`.

Comment: I've rewritten a part of the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77040644/how-to-make-a-verctorized-function-out-of-a-scalar-function-in-rust
Maybe it's redundant and the same answer applies, but the question is much more precise, which will add value for others who search for this problem.

Comment: Please don't get me wrong. I like your answer. I just need to accept it internally. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete runnable example for drewtato's answer. This is actually a comment to his answer, but the commenting feature can't take such a long post.

```
trait ScalarFn: Fn(f32) -> f32 {}
impl<F> ScalarFn for F where F: Fn(f32) -> f32 {}

pub trait VectorFn<const SIZE: usize>:
    FnMut(&[f32; SIZE], &mut [f32; SIZE]) {}

impl<const SIZE: usize, F> VectorFn<SIZE> for F
where
    F: FnMut(&[f32; SIZE], &mut [f32; SIZE]) {}

pub struct Layer<const SIZE: usize, F> {
    x: [f32; SIZE],
    y: [f32; SIZE],
    activation_fn: F,
}

impl<const SIZE: usize, F>
Layer<SIZE, F>
where
    F: VectorFn<SIZE>,
{
    pub fn new(activation_fn: F) -> Layer<SIZE, F> {
        let x = [0.0_f32; SIZE];
        let y = [0.0_f32; SIZE];

        Layer::<SIZE, F> { x: x, y: y, activation_fn: activation_fn }
    }

    pub fn activate(&mut self) {
        (self.activation_fn)(&self.y, &mut self.x);
    }
}

fn relu_scalar(x: f32) -> f32 {
    0.0_f32.max(x)
}

fn vectorized<const SIZE: usize, F>(inp: &[f32; SIZE], out: &mut [f32; SIZE], scalar_fn: F)
where
    F: ScalarFn,
{
    for i in 0..SIZE {
        out[i] = scalar_fn(inp[i]);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut layer = Layer::<10, _>::new(|inp, out| {
        vectorized(inp, out, relu_scalar)
    });

    layer.activate();
}
```