# Use a function's type as a generic argument

Tags: generics, optimization, rust

Take this (partially hypothetical) snippet here:

```rust
struct AddOneBefore<T: Fn(usize) -> usize>(T);
fn subtract_one(n: usize) -> usize { n - 1 }

type General = AddOneBefore<fn(usize) -> usize>;
const GENERAL: General = AddOneBefore(subtract_one);

// This is the hypothetical part:
// type Identity = AddOneBefore<{subtract_one}>;
// const IDENTITY: Identity = AddOneBefore(subtract_one);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=053e43988ec0fec3f233116134e53071)

Now, to let Rust best work its generics magic, I want to use the `Identity` type as opposed to `General`. Specifically, I believe `General` has to store a function pointer where as `Identity` *could* be a ZST. Similarly, the compiler can often inline and optimize function calls for generics, in theory reducing `IDENTITY` to a no-op whereas `GENERAL` may still need to preform the function call because it only has a pointer.

The main problem is that I can not find a way to specify the type of the `subtract_one` function (`AddOneBefore<{subtract_one}>` causes a compiler error)

In this simple snippet, there is likely little to no change, and the compiler may even be able to preform this optimization. In my case I will be using this type for an associated type `Map`-iterator in a trait which could potentially be deeply nested, meaning the memory cost would add up if it can't be optimized out. Is there any way around this?

In my real usecase I can implement an iterator to solve this problem manually, but I'd much rather rely on the `std::iter` types which are thoroughly implemented i.e specialize `size_hint`, implement traits like `DoubleEndedIterator`, etc. More generally, like in the example above, the most composable solution would require a ZST with an experimental `Fn` impl, but it seems like there should be another way.

This is similar to the question posed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77034476/how-to-use-a-function-as-a-generics-argument-in-rust), but I am more interested in writing out the type than providing the type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this the way you are wanting to with the unstable [type_alias_impl_trait](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2515-type_alias_impl_trait.html) feature. I don't believe there is a way to accomplish your goal in stable Rust, as it lacks a mechanism to give a name to specific function and closure types.

```
#![feature(type_alias_impl_trait)]

struct AddOneBefore<T: Fn(usize) -> usize>(T);
fn subtract_one(n: usize) -> usize { n - 1 }

type SubtractOneFn = impl Fn(usize) -> usize;
const GENERAL: AddOneBefore<SubtractOneFn> = AddOneBefore(subtract_one);
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5045cefafe8326c520ac111d0e8b896c))